# ¿cómo corregir este error lanzando el proyecto?

Tags: netbeans

Debo resolver este error en NetBeans. Estoy intentando iniciar mi 1er proyecto pero algo está fallando. Gracias

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.887 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.portfolio.vane.VaneApplicationTests
contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6cdee57 testClass = com.portfolio.vane.VaneApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.portfolio.vane.VaneApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@7d4f9aae, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@273e7444, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@52719fb6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@298a5e20, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@de5c2cfa], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL17Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL17Dialect]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL17Dialect

Results:

Errors: 
  VaneApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationCon...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

BUILD FAILURE

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project vane: There are test failures.
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Podrías compartir, al menos, las pruebas unitarias que tienes en `VaneApplicationTests`? Parece claro que el error proviene de ellas.

Comment: Hola Vane, estás segura de tener bien instalado Hibernate?, porque **Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL17Dialect**, parece indicar que no lo encuentra.

Comment: Hola Marce, ahí me fijé y vi que no, resulta que estuve probando pero no pude corregirlo todavía, me salta un error de validación